# Flutter web app won't deploy to Firebase hosting

Tags: flutter-web, firebase-hosting

My Flutter app looks great in the Chrome (web) emulator and running on a local server.

I navigated to this directory:

```
Users/TDK/StudioProjects/kabbalah/build/web/
```

I installed the Firebase CLI tools and then ran

```
firebase init hosting
```

I wasn't sure about this question:

```
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? (y/N)
```

I responded `y`. The response was

```
✔  Firebase initialization complete!
```

Then I ran

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

The response is

```
✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/kabbalah-numerology/overview
Hosting URL: https://kabbalah-numerology.web.app
```

When I go to the Project Console I see

```
Deployed
```

When I go to `https://kabbalah-numerology.web.app` I get this screen:

[image]

Shouldn't I see my web app? Did I deploy from the wrong directory?

I opened Safari to check if Chrome was cacheing an old webpage but I got the same screen.

I put this code block into `index.html`. It made no difference.

```html
<body>
<script>
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "my-super-secret-key",
  authDomain: "kabbalah-numerology.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "kabbalah-numerology",
  storageBucket: "kabbalah-numerology.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "my-sending-id",
  appId: "my-app-id",
  measurementId: "my-measurement-id"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the `firebase.json` file, which controls your hosting setup. Most likely the `public` folder in there, which determines from what directory files are served, points to the wrong location.

I typically run `firebase init` in the root of my project, and then point `public` in `firebase.json` to the output of the flutter web build.

Comment: Yay! That worked. I refactored `firebase.json` to `"public": "build/web",`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

Upon running `flutter clean`, `flutter build web --release` and `firebase init`, you will reach at this point as shown in the image: [image: setting public directories]

Choose No at the *File build/web/index.html already exists. Overwrite? (y/N)*. This is because Firebase overwrites the /index.html with its own code that generates the screen that you are viewing.

After that, you can run `firebase deploy`.

Alternatively, if you have already at the point where you see that ***firebase hosting setup complete*** screen, just run `flutter build web --release` to configure the build/web/index.html to your project and `firebase deploy`